# Vue ajax request isn't updating data

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue but from my research this should be working. the console keeps showing users as null but when i look at the response of the request it has the users. I thought the => was supposed to update the vue instance.

```js
...
data () {
  return {
    users: null,
  }
},
...
methods: {
  getUsers () {
    this.$axios.get('/api/users')
      .then(r => {
        this.users = r.data
      })
    console.log(this.users)
  },
},
...
created () {
  this.getUsers()
  this.users.forEach(function (u) {
    ...
  })
}
```

Comment: try to move `console.log` call to the `then` closure and see what it returns. call is asynchronous so it won't update `user` property until it receives the response.

Comment: that worked, but i guess my real question comes from the created method where I call getUsers. Right after the call I try to run through each user with a foreach but i get a TypeError on foreach because this.users is null. I assume this is because I call getUsers and sense it's async it runs the foreach before the ajax request is complete?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're looping through the returned results from within the script rather than in the template? If you show me your whole component I can get sort it out for you, but first make sure that your `users` is by default an array `users: []` rather than `null`.

Comment: You could run the forEach on `r.data`, before assigning to `this.users`. Or you could make `getUsers` async and do `this.getUsers().then(() => { this.users.forEach(...) })`

Comment: @SebastianSulinski this is because I need a list of options for a select input. The options are the users. Also, because i'm new and don't know much yet.

Comment: @Chris - the best thing to do would be to actually return the collection you need directly from the server rather than doing it in the browser. Sometimes returning collection of whole records / models might reveal some data that the front end user should not see such as passwords etc. You could run `array_map` on the server (that is if you're using php) to return it in the format you need - I'll add it to my answer in a moment.

Comment: Yep! i'm doing that already. Although there is more data than just the name and id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop through the collection of users, you have to first wait until they are actually available - you can use `then` callback for it:

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      users: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers () {
      return this.$axios.get('/api/users')
        .then(r => {
          this.users = r.data
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
  },
  created () {
    this.getUsers().then(() => {
      this.users.forEach(function (u) {
      ...
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Rather than converting returned collection from within vue component it would be better to return it formatted with the response - using plain php you could achieve it with `array_map` - here I'm using an array of `User` models as an example:

```php
$users = array_map(function (User $user) {
    return [
        'value' => $user->id,
        'name' => $user->name,
    ];
}, $users);
```

The above will return something like:

```php
[
    [
        'value' => 1,
        'name' => 'Jon Doe',
    ],
    [
        'value' => 2,
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
    ],
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can move your users processing to a watcher:

```
...
data () {
  return {
    users:[],
  }
},
watch: {
  users (users) {
    if( ! this.users.length )
       return;
    this.users.forEach(function (u) {
      ...
    })
  },
},
...
methods: {
  getUsers () {
    this.$axios.get('/api/users')
      .then(r => {
        this.users = r.data
      })
    console.log(this.users)
  },
},
...
created () {
  this.getUsers()
}
```

Or if you prefer a one time processing, make it a method and call that method in the axios then():

```
...
methods: {
  getUsers () {
    this.$axios.get('/api/users')
      .then(r => {
        this.users = r.data
        this.processUsers();
      })
    console.log(this.users)
  },
  processUsers() {
     // do something with this.users
  },
},
```

Comment: I initially downvoted because you answered without testing (basically your initial solution didn't work). After you changed it to use a watcher, I kept my downvote as using a watcher for updating vm after a single API call is a really bad pattern. A watcher runs until you destroy the component. On every single tick. Why? When all you need to do is run it in the `.then()` of the call and not have a watcher at all? It works, but it's bad practice, IMHO.

Comment: Besides, your solution risks running the forEach which could be anything, including something that mutates users more than once. Again, a dangerous practice.

Comment: @tao, thank you for taking the time, now I've learned something too!

Comment: Watchers are appropriate when running async and/or expensive operations in response to (rather frequent) changes in data or computed. They are rarely (if ever) appropriate for mapping responses. This is well documented [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property).